# Vaadin Combobox does not shows nameField from database

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I have a service class. When I set items alldata() in my combo box then it shows all the embedded data from the database. how can I just set the name field?

example:

private ComboBox groundComboBox = new ComboBox<>("Ground");
groundComboBox.setItems(groundService.getAllGround());

it shows:

Ground(groundId=Shere-Bangla, groundName=Shere-Bangla national stadium, city=Dhaka, country=Bangladesh, longitude=90.8, latitude=45.7, capacity=10000, inaugurationDate=2005-02-05).

i just want to show the only name;

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the label generator to define what will be the label of each item.

```
groundComboBox.setItemLabelGenerator(Ground::getName);
```

or

```
groundComboBox.setItemLabelGenerator(ground -> ground.getName());
```

Comment: In addition to this, you should always define the type of `ComboBox`, in this case it is a `ComboBox<Ground>`